# How to exclude elements by classname from selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="container">
  <p class="text">First</p>
  <p class="text">Second</p>
  <p class="text other">Third</p>
  <p class="text last">Fourth</p>
</div>
```

using `document.getElementsByClassName('text')` I get all 4 elements. How can I select every element with class `text` but **NOT** class `last`? `text other` should also be selected.

Is there some simple way to achieve this with Javascript/JQuery?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:not()` selector so it should be `$('.text:not(.last)')` or `$('.text').not('.last')`

```js
$('.text:not(.last)').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p class="text">First</p>
  <p class="text">Second</p>
  <p class="text other">Third</p>
  <p class="text last">Fourth</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `querySelectorAll` with `not`

```
document.querySelectorAll('p.text:not(.last)');
```

Answer (score 1):

With HTML5 selector API `querySelectorAll()` and `:not()` selector:

`document.querySelectorAll('.text:not(.last)')`

**Working Code Example:**

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.text:not(.last)').forEach(function(p){
  console.log(p.textContent)
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <p class="text">First</p>
  <p class="text">Second</p>
  <p class="text other">Third</p>
  <p class="text last">Fourth</p>
</div>
```

With jQuery `$('.text:not(.last)')`

**Working Code Example:**

```js
$('.text:not(.last)').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <p class="text">First</p>
  <p class="text">Second</p>
  <p class="text other">Third</p>
  <p class="text last">Fourth</p>
</div>
```